# How can I set callback URL for PayPal gateway on WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to set a callback URL to send the order data to a specific URL if payment is paid and etc..but I must that it will come same as it sent from PayPal IPN

Comment: Hi, please give more specific details about your issue, and what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

The standard WooCommerce module already uses IPN for processing, and only one IPN can be sent -- so replacing or overriding that IPN would not be a good idea. There is a newer/better WooCommerce plugin for PayPal available, which is not so dependent on IPN, so maybe switch to that: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/

And separately from IPN, you can subscribe to Webhook events for PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED and etc.
Webhooks are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/

Comment: I tried their plugin now (https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/) but is not working is not show any field to set up my paypal there